# Can't find template for C++ in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I bought a new laptop and Visual Studio was already installed in it, I want to write programs in C++ in Visual Studio 2015, but I could not find the template for C++. There are blank templates available for different languages but not for C++. Please help me out.

Comment: This should walk you through it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio works with a lot of languages. There are a lot of version Of VS too. So:

- Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Programs, Click Programs and Features and then select the Visual Studio Edition. Click Uninstall/Change. In the setup wizard, select Modify and then click Next. Select C++ in list of languages.

OR

- Go to Microsoft and download Community version of Visual C++ ([MS](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs))

Comment: Thanks a lot for help your first option worked perfectly.. But now I am facing problem while running the cpp files in visual studio 2015.. It says there are build errors and does not show the output.. How to resolve this. Could you please help me again

Comment: @Priyansh Verma I think best way is to learn programming. Read some book or take some course. If taking of offline course is not possible for you -> search https://coursera.org/. About your question ("It says there are build errors and does not show the output") - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve